# How can I show the progress process to client

Tags: c#

I am using C# 4.0 and I want to show the progress after button click.

```
protected void ASPxButton_cloture_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    tell user that procedure 1 begin
    do procedure 1.....
    tell user that procedure 1 finish

    tell user that procedure 2 begin
    do procedure 2.....
    tell user that procedure 2 finish

    etc...
}
```

I have tried with an update panel, but it only works one per button. That means when I have 5 procedures, I have to have 5 buttons.

What I want is to have only 1 button click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
protected void ASPxButton_cloture_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Write("procedure 1 begin");
    Response.Flush();
    // do procedure 1.....
    Response.Write("procedure 1 finish");
    Response.Flush();

    Response.Write("procedure 2 begin");
    Response.Flush();
    // do procedure 2.....
    Response.Write("procedure 2 finish");
    Response.Flush();

    // ...
}
```